# Pinning button to bottom of flexbox column layout, margin-top:auto not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I am new to flexbox, and just trying to do a set of columns that will stay the same width/height as the one with the most content, and I seem to have gotten that part working correctly.  My issue is trying to pin the button to align to the bottom of the columns.

I have read tons of examples of using `margin-bottom` to achieve this, but it does not work for me. Any help appreciated... as you can see, my skills are rudimentary at best.  TIA

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 24%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.list {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dir_button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #956a51;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80%;
}

button.dir_button {
  margin-top: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col">

    <div class="list">

      List item List itemList itemList item List item<br />

      <button type="button" class="dir_button">EMAIL</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

    <div class="list"> List item List item<br> List item<br>
      <p> List item</p>
      <p>List item </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

    <div class="list"> List item<br> List item<br> List item<br> List item<br>
      <p><br>
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

    <div class="list"> List item List item<br> List item<br> List item<br>
      <p><br>
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Make the list which contains the button display flex, the margin trick only works on flex items which is a child of flex container. Your button resides in an flex item which is not a flex container so it doesn't work. Make sure the flow is column so it goes up and down

Comment: I have no idea how you added your image, I suggest you try to add the image again and if it breaks, you post your breaking code on another question which I am sure it will be fairly straight forward to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `list` a *column flexbox* - note that *margin alignment* along the *flex axis* (vertical for a *column flexbox*) only works *inside* a flexbox i.e. it works only on *flex items* - see demo below:

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 24%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.list {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-direction: column; /* added */
}

.dir_button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #956a51;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80%;
}

button.dir_button {
  margin-top: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="list">
      List item List itemList itemList item List item<br />
      <button type="button" class="dir_button">EMAIL</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="list"> List item List item<br> List item<br>
      <p> List item</p>
      <p>List item </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="list"> List item<br> List item<br> List item<br> List item<br>
      <p><br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="list"> List item List item<br> List item<br> List item<br>
      <p><br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - - I had been staring at this all day and would have never figured that out.  Much appreciated!